# JLabel not updating with timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have searched all over the internet trying to find how to make an automatic updating clock gui program with no luck. I have tried many different methods, ending with the same results. I am using the swing Timer as I have read that's the best way to deal with gui's. I have tried validate(), revalidate(), repaint().
Here is part of the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
//import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ClockPanel extends JPanel { 
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE); 
    int second = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    private String currentTime;
    private JLabel current;

    public ClockPanel() {
        super();
        currentTime = getTime();
        current = new JLabel(currentTime);
        add(current);

        ActionListener updater = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                getTime();
                if(second == 60){
                    current.setText(currentTime);
                    revalidate();

                }
                getTime();
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, updater);
        timer.start();
    }
```

This is the final code that I have ended up with; I know it's wrong, but I have changed it so much for hours that I gave up. Thanks

EDIT: Here's the rest of the code

```
public String getTime() {
        String time;
        String period = "AM";
        String monthName = "";
        switch(month) {
            case (1):
                monthName = "January";
                break;
            case (2):
                monthName = "February";
                break;
            case (3):
                monthName = "March";
                break;
            case (4):
                monthName = "April";
                break;
            case (5):
                monthName = "May";
                break;
            case (6):
                monthName = "June";
                break;
            case (7):
                monthName = "July";
                break;
            case (8):
                monthName = "August";
                break;
            case (9):
                monthName = "September";
                break;
            case (10):
                monthName = "October";
                break;
            case (11):
                monthName = "November";
                break;
            case (12):
                monthName = "December";
                break;
        }
        if(hour >= 12){
            period = "PM";
        }
        time = monthName + " " + day + ", " + year + " "
                + hourCheck(hour) + ":" + minuteCheck(minute) + period;
        return time;
    }

    private int hourCheck(int hour) {
        if(hour > 12){
            hour -= 12;
            return hour;
        }
       if(hour == 0) {
            hour += 12;
            return hour;
        }
       return hour;
    }

    private StringBuilder minuteCheck(int minute) { 
       StringBuilder time = new StringBuilder();

       if(minute < 10) {
           return time.append("0").append(minute);
       }
       else {
           time.append("").append(minute);
       }
       return time;
    }

}
```

Comment: any compiler errors in your code...? it seems

Comment: Can you post the code of method `getTime()`?

Comment: I don't have any errors inside the compiler. I'm using netbeans if that helps

Comment: I think you can replace getTime() with a 'SimpleDateFormat' instance. Saves you a lot of trouble and is way more flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `getTime()`, but ignoring what it returns. The current time thus stays as it was before. Replace your code with:

```
    ActionListener updater = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String newTime = getTime();
            current.setText(newTime);
        }
    };
```

EDIT :

Not only do you ignore the value returned by `getTime()`, but `getTime()` also always returns the same thing, since you're always reuse the month, minute, seconds, etc. that have been initialized only once, when the panel has been constructed. You're also making your life really difficult by not using the standard DateFormat class.

Remove ALL the fields from your panel except the JLabel, and change the `getTime()` method to something like this:

```
private String getTime() {
    // get the CURRENT date:
    Date currentDate = new Date();

    // format it and return it:
    return new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a").format(currentDate);
}
```

Comment: I have a getTime() function that returns time. I can post the whole code if you like. It will probably make it easier

Comment: As you told: it RETURNS the time. So if you ignore what it RETURNS, calling it doesn't change anything. Re-read my answer, and try the code I posted. Also see Genzer's example, which is complete and does what you want.

Comment: @TechnicalCustoms: read my edited answer. Your getTime() method is also wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. I've been searching around for hours, and you give it in 5 minutes. Thanks +1

Answer (score 2):

You could adjust your code to this and it will work:

```
public class ClockPanel extends JPanel { 
    private final JLabel current;

    public ClockPanel() {
        current = new JLabel(now());
        add(current);

        new Timer (1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                current.setText(now());
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private static String now() {
        // implement your own
        return new Date().toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame main = new JFrame("Simple Clock");
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        main.setSize(200, 200);
        main.setContentPane(new ClockPanel());
        main.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the SSCCE, and for showing that all these fields in the panel are unnecessary.